# Error inserting array into PostgreSQL column: Malformed array literal

Tags: node.js, reactjs, postgresql, graphql, objection.js

I'm encountering an issue while trying to insert an array of strings into a PostgreSQL database column. The column is defined as follows:

```
path TEXT[] NOT NULL
```

here is the schema:

```
path: { type: 'array', items: { type: 'string' }, notNull: true }
```

here I send the format of path like this

```
await updateGlobalChatNotificationOptIn({
      variables: {
        path: ['chat'],
        option: updatedGlobalChatNotificationOptIn,
      },
```

```
updateNotificationOption(path: [String!]!, option: String!): NotificationUserOption
```

when I pass the path something like this  `['chat']`

```
  // If no existing record, create a new one
      return NotificationUserOption.query().upsertGraphAndFetch(
        { userId, path, groupId, option },
        { insertMissing: true },
      )
    },
    
  extend type Mutation {
    updateNotificationOption(path: [String!]!, option: String!): NotificationUserOption
  }
```

However, when I try to insert the array using this code, I encounter the following error:

> malformed array literal: "["chat"]"
> "[" must introduce explicitly-specified array dimensions.

I've tried using single brackets (`'{chat}'`) and double brackets (`[['chat']]`), but neither seems to work.

How can I correctly format the array literal so that I can insert the array into the PostgreSQL column without encountering this error?

Comment: Why do you use an array? Stick to a 3NF datamodel, that gives you a better datamodel that is also easier to use. And you don’t have issues like this